# Browser tab balancing software or extension?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, chromium

I use a window manager, which generally has the ability to balance windows really well. This gets defeated with tabs in browsers. Effectively this allows you to put multiple different things in one browser window, which makes organization a lot more difficult.

Is there a piece of software that can help with this? Such that opening up a new tab with

- GitLab or GitHub in any browser goes to my SCM browser window.
- Opening up a new Documentation page goes to my documentation browser window.

I'd like to be able to open a documentation page in my SCM browser window and have it re-balance that tab to my documentation browser window automatically.

I'm currently using Chrome, but I'm open to suggestions for Firefox too.